# detect transformed element to calculate position of fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want to calculate the position of a `position:fixed` element relative to the view port.
`position:fixed` is by definition relative to the closest view-port/transformed element so what i'm trying to do is find closest element with css `transform` that has a value other than `none` and sum their left/top values.
do you know of a better way to do this?

this method doesn't work on IE because on IE an element with the rule `transform:none` IE translates it to `transform:matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)` instead of `none`.

do you know how can i handle this weirdness in an elegant way, without having to detect which browser i'm in?
or alternatively do you know of a way to get the position of a fixed element, relative to view-port?

IE weirdness ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oriadam/sqv0gzj1/)):

```
console.log(getComputedStyle(el).transform); // 'none'
el.style.transform = "none";
console.log(getComputedStyle(el).transform); // 'matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)' but expecting 'none'
el.style.transform = "";
console.log(getComputedStyle(el).transform); // 'none'
```

the code ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oriadam/0npdkm24/)):

```
$.fn.parentFix = function() {
  let parent = this[0].offsetParent;
  while (parent && getComputedStyle(parent)['transform'] === 'none') // THIS LINE FAILS ON IE11 UNLESS I ADD CHECK FOR "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)"
    parent = parent.offsetParent;
  return parent ? $(parent) : $('body');
};
```

p.s.
i stopped using jQuery for this because 3.4.1 changed the way `position()` works - it is now relative to closest td/th/table or body.

Comment: please post relevant code (reduced version) for your question here on this site.

Comment: sure. getting right to it

Comment: maybe you should use a polyfill (like https://github.com/jonathantneal/Polyfills-for-IE8/blob/master/getComputedStyle.js) and force your solution (or at least IE regardless to its version) to use it.. this way you can control the output of `none` (force it to return proper value instead of matrix)